# What is the right way to test significant for paired distance matrices?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, distance

I have distance matrices of two clusters, each one represents the genomic distance between all of the cluster's species.

Here is a density plot of the distance values within the clusters between the clusters:

[image]

- The two clusters are not equal in size
- Distance values do not correspond to a normal distribution.

I would like to test the significance of the within/between values distribution in order to find if I should merge those clusters or not.
I am not sure which statistical test to apply.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to check anything with your results. On your picture, the biggest intracluster distance is still much smaller than the smallest intercluster distance. There is no overlap of your two distributions at all. That means that you have a very strong, clear cluster structure.

Comment: Yes (: It is just one example, I have ~4000 other clusters

Comment: I doubt that you really need to do any significance testing (p-value). If you need to inspect how compact and isolated each of your clusters and whether its objects belong to it justifiedly, you might consider plotting Silhouette Width plot for each cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try some kind of permutation test, where you compare observed average distance within/between clusters with the value you get if you permute the labels. The permutations are used to build a distribution of expected distances - based on your chart, your observed average distance will fall well outside the expected distribution.

Try looking up MRPP - multi response permutation procedure - for some ideas. There are other permutation-based methods that will work too.